# Changing themes with sass and angular

Tags: angular, user-interface, sass, frontend

I'm using Angular5 and Sass to create a web apllication, in this application the user have an option to select the theme that will be used in the page.
I've used Sass variables to specify the colors that will change in each theme, and in the _variables.scss archive I have an if structure that changes this variables based on a $theme variable.

I also have a box with all the themes displayed and the user can select it, but how do I change the $theme variable based on selection? That code is also imported in another 3 scss archives to use its properties.

_variables Code:

```
$theme: 'default';

$layout-background: #21242b;
$layout-color: #fff;
$layout-button-color: #3B3E45;
$content-left: 187px;
$content-bg: #f9f9f9;
$footer-color: rgba(249, 249, 249,0.95);
$default-grad: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #444 100%);
$side-grad: linear-gradient(rgba(33, 36, 43, 0.8), rgba(27, 37, 65, 0.9)), url('../../assets/img/bg-sm.jpg');
$default-border: 1px solid black;
$inbox-color: #000;
$box-color: #fff;
$content-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 #ddd;
$hover-li: #000;

@if $theme == 'night'{
    $layout-background: #f3f3f3;
    $layout-color: #fff;
    $layout-button-color: #3B3E45;
    $content-left: 187px;
    $content-bg: #222;
    $footer-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.95);
    $default-grad: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(59, 62, 69), rgb(74, 81, 97) 100%);
    $side-grad: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.9)), url('../../assets/img/bg-sm.jpg');
    $default-border: 1px solid black;
    $inbox-color: #000;
    $box-color: #fff;
    $content-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
    $hover-li: #000;
}

@if $theme == 'sunny-day'{
    $layout-background: rgb(116, 57, 2);
    $layout-color: #fff;
    $layout-button-color: rgb(185, 59, 0);
    $content-left: 187px;
    $content-bg: #FFFBF9;
    $footer-color: rgba(255, 251, 249, 0.95);
    $default-grad: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(224, 92, 4), rgb(219, 62, 0) 100%);
    $side-grad: linear-gradient(rgba(190, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(206, 96, 7, 0.9)), url('../../assets/img/bg-sm.jpg');
    $default-border: 1px solid rgb(156, 0, 0);
    $inbox-color: #000;
    $box-color: #fff;
    $content-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgb(209, 184, 160);
    $hover-li: rgb(83, 0, 0);
}

@if $theme == 'jungle'{
    $layout-background: rgb(0, 37, 0);
    $layout-color: #fff;
    $layout-button-color: rgb(3, 99, 0);
    $content-left: 187px;
    $content-bg: #f1fae4;
    $footer-color: rgba(241, 250, 228, 0.95);
    $default-grad: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(24, 80, 0), rgb(34, 110, 2) 100%);
    $side-grad: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 190, 25, 0.8), rgba(0, 44, 18, 0.9)), url('../../assets/img/bg-sm.jpg');
    $default-border: 1px solid rgb(0, 41, 5);
    $inbox-color: #000;
    $box-color: #fff;
    $content-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgb(49, 53, 43);
    $hover-li: rgb(11, 68, 0);
}

@if $theme == 'light-blue'{
    $layout-background: #88adb8;
    $layout-color: #fff;
    $layout-button-color: #008DA7;
    $content-left: 187px;
    $content-bg: #f9f9f9;
    $footer-color: rgba(249, 249, 249,0.95);
    $default-grad: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 101, 119), rgb(3, 125, 146) 100%);
    $side-grad: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 124, 161, 0.8), rgba(0, 175, 228, 0.8)), url('../../assets/img/bg-sm.jpg');
    $default-border: 1px solid rgb(0, 140, 175);
    $inbox-color: #000;
    $box-color: #fff;
    $content-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 #ddd;
    $hover-li: rgb(0, 88, 110);
}
```